# DOM queryCommandValue when nothing is selected

Tags: dom, vb6

I want to use document.queryCommandValue("FontName") to return the name of the font where the caret is positioned but it only seems to return a value if one or more characters are selected. For example, if I click in the middle of a word it returns "" as the font name unless I drag over one or more characters.

How can I get it to return the fontname for where the caret is (ie. which font will be used if I start typing?)

Comment: When you move your mousepointer over the tag, a short info will orccour. The following words are mentioned "Use this tag on questions regarding the interaction of other languages ...". So which programmar language do/did you use?

Comment: I'm using VB6 and accessing the DOM of a WebBrowser object.